# Tool besides ida to get high level code

Tags: ida, disassembly, decompilation

I looking another tool besides ida to get high level code from binary file.(like oda pesudocode)

I know that the high level is not perfect on every tool, but I want try another tool.

My code compile to arm.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Retargetable Decompiler](https://github.com/avast-tl/retdec).

hugsy has developed a [Binary Ninja](https://binary.ninja/) plugin to decompile binaries using the RetDec API called [binja-retdec](https://github.com/hugsy/binja-retdec).

Comment: @SYS_Y what Retargetable Decompiler diffrent than Binary Ninja. Witxh better?  And they bettwr than ida psudocode??

Comment: RetDec only works at present with 32-bit binaries. It  has a 32-bit IDA Pro plugin for generating either C or pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac or Linux, [hopper](https:///www.hopperapp.com/) is a product worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

Currently nothing beats the quality of IDA’s ARM decompiler.

But if you are on a budget, BinaryNinja’s medium level IL is actually quite pleasant to read. And in my experience it’s correct (while retdec’s C code is sometimes just plain wrong).

The JEB guys have entered the decompiler business with a MIPS decompiler (which HexRays doesn’t offer at the moment). Supposedly it’s quite good. And they have a ARM decompiler in open beta now. I have not tried it yet, but it’s good to see competition.

Answer (score 0):

If you on Windows then [Relyze Desktop](https://www.relyze.com/overview.html) contains a decompiler for ARM binaries (As well as ARM64/x86/x64).